# Evaluating different conditions in one if statement on a stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored proc I am trying to write , where I want to evaluate multiple conditions on the different parameters in one go. What is the best syntax for this?

Below is what I have:

```
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @GARRISON nvarchar(255)
    DECLARE @ASSETTYPE nvarchar(255)
    DECLARE @FIVALUE int

    IF (  ( @GARRISON IS NOT 'Netheravon' 
            AND @GARRISON IS NOT 'Ludgershall'
          )
          AND @INTERRUPT >= 5)
        BEGIN

        END
    ELSE

END
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use.

```
IF ((@GARRISON != 'Netheravon' AND @GARRISON != 'Ludgershall') )
AND @INTERRUPT >= 5)
```

This can be shortened to

```
IF (@GARRISON NOT IN ('Netheravon', 'Ludgershall' )
AND @INTERRUPT >= 5)
```

The problem you had was that you have `@variable IS NOT 'constant'` - this isnt valid SQL Syntax unless checking for null. For equality use `=`, for non-equality use `!=` or `<>` (Both work IIRC).

---

Edit: This is the exact sctipt I used for testing, and works exactly as expected. SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE @GARRISON nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @INTERRUPT INT

SET @GARRISON = 'Test'
SET @INTERRUPT = 10


IF (@GARRISON NOT IN ('Netheravon' ,'Ludgershall' )
   AND @INTERRUPT >= 5)  
BEGIN
SELECT 1
END
```

The above correctly outputs "1" as both conditions evaluate true. If I either change `@INTERRUPT` to 4, or `@GARRISON` to either Netheravon or Ludgershall then there is no output. This is the exact behaviour I expect.

Note: You can't have an empty `BEGIN...END` block in SQL, so if that is empty you'll get the error `Incorrect syntax near 'END'.`

Comment: Thanks for that, will do it now.

Comment: @dotnetdev - define "didnt work". What was your expected result and what actually happened.

Comment: I was expecting the q uery to compile, but got incorrect syntax errors.

Comment: @dotnetdev - I suspect youve still got your erroneous `IS NOT` in there somewhere. This is not valid syntax unless working with null. My change was subtle - I changed `IS NOT` to `NOT IN`. Check the update.

Comment: So I have the query in a better sharep. I have put a select in the  begin...end block, but still get incorrect syntax near end?

Comment: Have you tried my test script in this post? Also do you really have an orphaned `ELSE` as per your original Post?

Comment: I managed to get it working, believe it was the way the query ended (made a new stored proc and took yours it worked, then copied my bit over). Thanks